# how to copy all the child nodes from a parent node using XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xls

below is my input :

```
<csv>
<row>
    <stuff>a</stuff>
    <more>1</more>
    <evenmore>123</evenmore>
    <roww>
        <other>1345</other>
       <other>13845</other>
    </roww>
</row>
</csv>
```

OutPut Expected :

```
 <roww>
        <other>1345</other>
       <other>13845</other>
    </roww>
```

Can anyone let me know how to do it with XSL?

Comment: Please show what XSL commands you have already tried

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's simply to match the parent node and do `copy-of`.

**The `<xsl:copy-of>` element creates a copy of the current node.**

Note: Namespace nodes, child nodes, and attributes of the current node are automatically copied as well!

The **XSLT 1.0** solution to achieve your expected output can be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/csv">
    <xsl:copy-of select="row/roww" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y93

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeOps tree transformation visual tool to achieve this.
TreeOps(https://github.com/treeops/treeops):

1. Load XML
2. add transformation - Move up "row/roww/other"
3. add transformation - Move up "row/other"
4. add transformation - Delete "row"

[Input and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSelL.png)
[Transformations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1oLn.png)